# Java: 'Invalid line number' when setting boolean grid to all true

Tags: java, grid, boolean

I'm trying to set the below Grid to all true, but I get the error

> "2685 is not a valid line number in java.util.Arrays"

```
public class Grid {

    static boolean[][] gridCon;
    boolean white = true;
    boolean black = false;
    private static int Height;
    private static int Width;

    public Grid(int height, int width) {

        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        Arrays.fill(gridCon, true);

    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays.fill does not work with 2-dimentional arrays, try this

```
gridCon = new boolean[Height][Width]; 
for(boolean [] e : gridCon) {
    Arrays.fill(e, true);
}
```

Comment: Another problem I didn't notice. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the array with `gridCon = new boolean[Height][Width];`
If that doesn't work, post the full error please

Comment: Sure thing.  Be sure to check the arrow so nobody else responds

Comment: Somebody else might have a better answer ;)